# jQuery toggle class on dynamically assigned class

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I'm trying to toggle a class on a single button, where the class would be dynamically assigned based on a state. Here is my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
    var $itm = $(this).children(".icon");
    if ($itm.hasClass('hide')) {
        $itm.toggleClass('unhide', 'hide')
    } else {
        $itm.toggleClass('hide', 'unhide')
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:
If a button has class `.hide`, the `onclick` toggles this class to `.unhide`, and vice versa.

So far the only time class toggling works is, is on the second click. The first click does not change anything.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're applying to this, and an example at jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Sure, here is the link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gLHrn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.toggleClass` accepts one or more class names separated by a space like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
    $(this).children(".icon").toggleClass("hide unhide");
});
```

Working example (with a tweak to your HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9tV33/

Comment: @friend00 I can't believe, I missed something simple like that. Thank you